# Eliminar linea null archivo creado CMD

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch

Tengo un batch el cual toma el nombre del archivo y ruta de un parámetro en una tabla y luego ejecuta un select y lo guarda en un txt. El problema que se está dando es que en la última línea me crea un registro con NULL (voy a adjuntar imágen) lo cual hace que de error el sistema que toma este archivo. A continuacion les copio el batch
REM - PRUEBA

```
  for /f  %%A in  ('sqlcmd -S Vane -d PEPE-U sa -P Vane -Q "set nocount on;select (SELECT Valor FROM ParametrosVarios WHERE Codigo = 1000)+NombreArchivo+replace(convert(varchar,(SELECT FechaProcesoAnterior FROM para),2),'.','')+'.txt' FROM Interfaz_NombresArchivos WHERE Id=3"') do set Nombre="%%A"
    SET result=%Nombre:/= % 
    echo %result% 
    sqlcmd -S Vane -d PEPE-U sa -P Vane -Q "set nocount on; delete from Interfaz_Prueba where fechaejecucion = convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120)"
    sqlcmd -S Vane -d PEPE -U sa -P Vane -Q "set nocount on; BEGIN exec sp_Interfaz_Prueba END"
    sqlcmd -S Vane -d PEPE -U sa -P Vane -Q "set nocount on; select CAST(entidad as varchar)+NroOperacion+cast(SucursalOperacion as varchar)+CAST(entidad as varchar)+cast(Producto as varchar)+cast(Subproducto as varchar)+Moneda+cast(SucursalOperacion as varchar)+replicate(' ',4)+cast(CanalDeVenta as varchar)+cast(OficialVenta as varchar)+cast(OficialComercial as varchar)+replicate(' ',4-datalength(OficialComercial))+cast(saldo as varchar)+cast(saldo as varchar)+fechaInicio+'9999-12-31'+EstadoDelContrato+FechaEstado+replicate(' ',2)+replicate(' ',2)+replicate(' ',8)+replicate(' ',20)+'0000BANKTRADE'+REPLICATE(' ',111)+TipoMovimiento from Interfaz_Prueba where fechaejecucion = convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120)"  -o %result% -W -w 1024 -s"" -h-1
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Buenas

Puedes probar a usar este otro for al final de tu script para coger lo que quieres del fichero

```
for /f "delims=loQueSea" %%i in (ficheroSinTratar.txt) do >> ficheroTratado.txt echo %%i
```

Este for te va a coger todas las lineas del fichero llamado **ficheroSinTratar.txt** que no empiecen por **loQueSea** (detrás del delims) y te los va a meter a un nuevo archivo llamado **ficheroTratado.txt**

Un saludo y espero que te haya servido

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: al final era porque los datos eran migrados de un AS400 y tomaba caracteres especiales !